# Random value from cloud datastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I'm writing a python program to save and retrieve a customer data in cloud datastore. My entity looks like below:

```
entity.update({
        'customerId': args['customerId'],
        'name': args['name'],
        'email': args['email'],
        'city': args['city'],
        'mobile': args['mobile']
    })
    datastore_client.put(entity)
```

I'm successfully saving the data. Now, I want to retrieve a random email id from the a record. I have written the below code:

```
def get_customer():
    query = datastore_client.query(kind='CustomerKind')
    results = list(query.fetch())
    chosen_customer = random.choice(results)
    print(chosen_customer)
```

But instead getting only one random email id, I'm getting the entire row like this:

```
<Entity('CustomerKind', 6206716152643584) {'customerId': '103', 'city': 'bhubaneswar', 'name': 'Amit', 'email': 'amit@gmail.com', 'mobile': '7879546732'}>
```

Can anyone suggest how can I get only **'email': 'amit@gmail.com'** ? I'm new to datastore.

Comment: you got the whole entry. To extract from it, you might be able to just use `chosen_customer["email"]`

Answer (score 1):

When using

```
query = datastore_client.query(kind='CustomerKind')
results = list(query.fetch())
```

you are retrieving all the properties from all the entities that will be returned.

Instead, you can use a [projection query](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projections), which allows you to retrieve only the specified properties from the entities:

```
query = client.query(kind="CustomerKind")
query.projection = ["email"]
results = list(query.fetch())
```

Using projection queries is recommended for cases like this, in which you only need some properties as they [reduce cost and latency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#queries).